# What is a sensible way to store matrices (which represent images) either in memory or on disk, to make them available to a GUI application?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, matrix, pyqt

I am looking for some high level advice about a project that I am attempting.

I want to write a PyQt application (following the [model-view pattern](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/model-view-programming.html)) to read in images from a directory one by one and process them. Typically there will be a few thousand .png images (each around 1 megapixel, 16 bit grayscale) in the directory. After being read in, the application will then process the integer pixel values of each image in some way, and crucially the result will be a matrix of floats for each. Once processed, the user should be able be able to then go back and explore any of the matrices they choose (or multiple at once), and possibly apply further processing.

My question is regarding a sensible way to store the matrices in memory, and access them when needed. After reading in the raw .png files and obatining the corresponding matrix of floats, I can then see the following options for handling the result:

1. Simply **store each matrix as a numpy array and have every one of them stored in a class attribute**. That way they will all be easily accessible to the code when requested by the user, but will this be poor in terms of RAM required?
2. After processing each, **write out the matrix to a text file**, and read it back in from the text file when requested by the user.
3. I have seen examples ([see here](https://www.giacomodebidda.com/mvc-pattern-in-python-sqlite/)) of people using **SQLite databases** to store data for a GUI application (using MVC pattern), and then query the database when you need access to data. This seems like it would have the advantage that data is not stored in RAM by the "model" part of the application (like in option 1), and is possibly more storage-efficient than option 2, but is this suitable given that my data are matrices?
4. I have seen examples ([see here](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/how-to-use-hdf5-files-in-python/)) of people using something called **HDF5** for storing application data, and that this might be similar to using a SQLite database? Again, suitable for matrices?
5. Finally, I see that PyQt has the classes **[QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) and [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html)**. Do these make sense for solving the problem I have described?

I am a little lost with all the options, and don't want to spend too much time investigating *all* of them in too much detail so would appreciate some general advice. If someone could offer comments on each of the options I have described (as well as letting me know if any can be ruled out in this situation) that would be great!

Thank you

Comment: I’d don’t really know about PyQt, but from a programming standpoint, I’d go with a dict of numpy arrays first (takes around 4GB of RAM, doable by most modern PCs). Then implementing HDF5 permanent storage should not be difficult since it can be interfaced just like a dict of numpy arrays. Keep in mind that storing bitmaps is quite inefficient and you might be well served by reexporting each image ASAP to a png file. (Maybe keep a thumbnail in RAM, and load the original once the user scrolls near that particular image)

Comment: Yes. It’s at least worth thinking about that, I guess. No clue how fast SQLite is compared to Pillow, though. I guess personally I would use numpy because I’m familiar with it and it’s flexible (1000 * 1MB ~ 1GB, that’s phone territory), and if the need arises think of disc storage later.

Comment: I can't imagine 2) or 3) could be sensible options. By the way, 1000 one megapixel images is 3GB if colour (as opposed to greyscale) and potentially 6GB if 16-bit.

Comment: With regard to 2) Writing text to files rather than binary is just inefficient in terms of space and CPU cycles. Likewise with 3) databases are just not efficient for storing images and you end up with a massive, unwieldy file that's inefficient to backup. Of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell. When you say "write to binary", would this typically be done using the *numpy.ndarray.tofile* or *numpy.save* methods for this task?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer. I don't understand what you are trying to do, nor what problem you are really trying to solve. I don't see why you want to keep all images in memory when you can probably read any one you want from disk in around 30-50ms. I don't understand why you think you want to write images in a database, ASCII or text when the *"normal"* format for an image on disk is a PNG or JPEG or similar. I don't know what problem you are really trying to solve. If you improve your question I may be able to help better, at the moment, all I'd say is that text & database are probably not ideal.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear. What I am really trying to store (as in the question title) are matrices. Although the original data is read in the beginning from 16 bit png files (and therefore represented by matrices of 16 bit integers initially), there is then some processing applied by the application which means the matrices are no longer integers (in fact, they will actually be matrices of floats after processing). Therefore I can't simply write the data out as a "normal" png file anymore, and need a nice way to store matrices.

Comment: It's not that I "want to keep them in memory". I only mentioned that as option 1 because it was the simplest possible thing I could think of. That's the essence of the question - does it make more sense to write them out and read them in (using one of the available options I provided)? If so, which of the "writing out" options is most sensible, if any.

Comment: Ok, if the issue is saving floats, you could consider `numpy.save()` or saving as a TIFF image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks - I was not aware that TIFF could store floats.